# select everything from a table for a column

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.0

in my mysql database i have the following tables:

```
FACULTY (fid int, fname varchar(25), deptid int, primary key(fid))  
CLASS (name varchar(4),meets_at varchar(9),room varchar(4), fid int,primary key (name), foreign key (fid) references faculty (fid))
```

I want to select the names of faculties who go to all the rooms.
 I tried using following :

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.FNAME   
FROM FACULTY F  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (( SELECT *  
FROM CLASS C  
EXCEPT  
(SELECT C1.ROOM  
FROM CLASS C1  
   WHERE C1.FID=F.FID)));
```

and got the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'EXCEPT

also tried with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.FNAME   
FROM FACULTY F   
LEFT JOIN CLASS C ON C.FID = F.FID  
WHERE C.FID IS NULL
```

and got "Empty Set" even when in my database there is a faculty who goes to all the rooms.

Comment: Also please don't tag MySQL questions as `sql-server`.

Comment: Consider providing an sqlfiddle of same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `except` the two table must be `compatible`, try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.FNAME   
FROM FACULTY F  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
( SELECT ROOM  
FROM CLASS C)
EXCEPT  
(SELECT C1.ROOM  
FROM CLASS C1  
   WHERE C1.FID=F.FID)
);
```

**EDIT**

The question was tagged to sql server so I gave the answer keeping that in mind, for mysql use this :

```
SELECT FID, COUNT(*) FROM
(
    (SELECT DISTINCT f.fname, f.fid, c1.room 
    FROM faculty f
    JOIN class c1 
    ON f.fid = c1.fid) tb1 
JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT room AS room2 FROM class) tb2
ON tb1.room = tb2.room2
)
GROUP BY FID
HAVING COUNT(*) IN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Room) FROM Class);
```

fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/cff12/4

Comment: There is no `EXCEPT` in MySQL

Comment: @synder   as per you query i am getting a list of all those faculties' fid and count value who take more than one class. I want fname and fid for those who go to all rooms irrespective of count and class name. please checkout my both tables mentioned question.

Comment: @UmangAgrawal How are you getting more than one for eg. in this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f25e/5 `A` goes in every room viz. `RA` and `RB`. Can you give me an example where desired result not obtained ?

Comment: @synder: please see the following: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/cff12/1  wherein only faculty with fid 88451 and fname Prof Snehashu Saha goes to both the rooms i.e. R102 and R128 whereas Ms Bidisha and Ms Saraswathi go only to R102 for two  different classes. what i want is the name of the faculty who goes to all distinct class rooms.

Comment: @ synder: ya thats working...but what if i dont want the count and fid  to be displayed ???

Comment: @UmangAgrawal You can remove them from the select statement see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/cff12/5

Comment: @synder what if i want to do it using intersect or not exixts or not in clauses ??? Can v do it ??

Answer (score 0):

My point of view related to your problem.

```
SELECT T.fid FROM
  (SELECT f.fid FROM 
     faculty f LEFT JOIN class c ON f.fid = c.fid) T
  GROUP BY T.fid 
  HAVING(
    COUNT(T.fid) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT room) FROM class))
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69a6c/6)

Comment: as per you query i am getting a list of all those faculties' fid who take more than one class. I want fname and fid for those who go to all distinct rooms irrespective of count and class name. please checkout my both tables mentioned question